# Multiple array json parsing under a object in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

How Can I parse this data:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "ambulance":[  
         {  
            "ID":"1",
            "Title":"title1",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"2",
            "Title":"title1",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"3",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"4",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"5",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"6",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"7",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"8",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"9",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"10",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"11",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"12",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         }
      ],
      "bloodbank":[  
         {  
            "ID":"1",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"2",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"3",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         }
      ],
      "hospital":[  
         {  
            "ID":"1",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"2",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"3",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"4",
            "Title":"Charpara",
            "Longitude":"45.156849",
            "Latitude":"27.158945",
            "Address":"Mymensingh Medical College"
         },
         {  
            "ID":"5",
            "Title":"Sylhet Osmani Medical College",
            "Longitude":"78.1245887",
            "Latitude":"76.054846",
            "Address":"Osmani Meical College road, Sylher"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: what did you try? so far?

Comment: You parse it the same way as any other JSON

Comment: if you are new to JSON and confused with parsing, first paste the JSON content into a JSON viewer and observe it clearly, then you will get the answer you needed by understanding the structure of the data.
Nothing is tough actually in JSON, just there are two types, one is ARRAy which can be accessed as normal arrays with index like a[0], another is OBJECT whose properties can be accessed using a '.'(dot);

if you practice like this it will be easy for you to parse any complicated JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use from  [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)  and in `doInBackground` method you must have these code:

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


        JSONObject data = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");

        // Getting JSON Array node 
        JSONArray ambulance = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ambulance");
        // looping through All ambulance 
        for (int i = 0; i < ambulance.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString("ID");
            String Title = c.getString("Title");
            String Longitude = c.getString("Longitude");
            String Latitude = c.getString("Latitude");
            String Address = c.getString("Address");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say "data" is the name of your JSON string, then this will do (don't forget to catch JSONException):

```
JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(data).getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray ambulance = dataJson.getJSONArray("ambulance");
JSONArray bloodbank = dataJson.getJSONArray("bloodbank");
JSONArray hospital = dataJson.getJSONArray("hospital");
```

You can access the specific objects by iterating over the JSONArrays and calling ambulance.getJSONObject(i), for example. Then you just have to call getString("ID") and so on to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep proper data structure as per json.

In your case something like:

```
public class Response{
    public List<Ambulance> aList = new ArrayList<Ambulance>();
    public List<BloodBank> bList = new ArrayList<Ambulance>();

    //getter setter for both lists
}

public class Ambulance{
    private String  ID = "";
    private String  Title = "";
    private Double Longitude=0.0;
    private Double Latitude=0.0;
    private String  Address = "";
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

}

public class BloodBank{
    private String  ID = "";
    private String  Title = "";
    private Double Longitude=0.0;
    private Double Latitude=0.0;
    private String  Address = "";
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

}
```

And then parse as:

```
Response response = new Gson().fromJson(responseString,
                    Response.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
       try{
            String jsonResponse = "{\"data\":{\"ambulance\":[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"Title\":\"title1\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"2\",\"Title\":\"title1\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"4\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"5\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"6\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"7\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"8\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"9\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"10\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"11\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"12\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"}],\"bloodbank\":[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"2\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"}],\"hospital\":[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"2\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"4\",\"Title\":\"Charpara\",\"Longitude\":\"45.156849\",\"Latitude\":\"27.158945\",\"Address\":\"Mymensingh Medical College\"},{\"ID\":\"5\",\"Title\":\"Sylhet Osmani Medical College\",\"Longitude\":\"78.1245887\",\"Latitude\":\"76.054846\",\"Address\":\"Osmani Meical College road, Sylher\"}]}}";

             JSONObject responeJson = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
             JSONObject dataJson = responeJson.optJSONObject("data");

            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> ambulanceList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            JSONArray ambulanceJsonArray = dataJson.getJSONArray("ambulance");
            for(int i=0;i<ambulanceJsonArray.length();i++){
                HashMap<String,String> ambulanceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                ambulanceMap.put("ID", ambulanceJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"));
                ambulanceMap.put("Title", ambulanceJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Title"));
                ambulanceMap.put("Longitude", ambulanceJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Longitude"));
                ambulanceMap.put("Latitude", ambulanceJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Latitude"));
                ambulanceMap.put("Address", ambulanceJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Address"));
                ambulanceList.add(ambulanceMap);
            }

            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> hospitalList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            JSONArray hospitalJsonArray = dataJson.getJSONArray("hospital");
            for(int i=0;i<hospitalJsonArray.length();i++){
                HashMap<String,String> hospitalMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hospitalMap.put("ID", hospitalJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"));
                hospitalMap.put("Title", hospitalJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Title"));
                hospitalMap.put("Longitude", hospitalJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Longitude"));
                hospitalMap.put("Latitude", hospitalJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Latitude"));
                hospitalMap.put("Address", hospitalJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Address"));
                hospitalList.add(hospitalMap);
            }

            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> bloodbankList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            JSONArray bloodbankJsonArray = dataJson.getJSONArray("bloodbank");
            for(int i=0;i<bloodbankJsonArray.length();i++){
                HashMap<String,String> bloodbankMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                bloodbankMap.put("ID", bloodbankJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"));
                bloodbankMap.put("Title", bloodbankJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Title"));
                bloodbankMap.put("Longitude", bloodbankJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Longitude"));
                bloodbankMap.put("Latitude", bloodbankJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Latitude"));
                bloodbankMap.put("Address", bloodbankJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Address"));
                bloodbankList.add(bloodbankMap);
            }


            for (int i=0;i<ambulanceList.size();i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> ambulanceMapData = ambulanceList.get(i);
                System.out.print("ID :" + ambulanceMapData.get("ID"));
                System.out.print("Title :" + ambulanceMapData.get("Title"));
                System.out.print("Longitude :" + ambulanceMapData.get("Longitude"));
                System.out.print("Latitude :" + ambulanceMapData.get("Latitude"));
                System.out.print("Address :" + ambulanceMapData.get("Address"));
            }
            for (int i=0;i<bloodbankList.size();i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> bloodbankMapData = bloodbankList.get(i);
                System.out.print("ID :" + bloodbankMapData.get("ID"));
                System.out.print("Title :" + bloodbankMapData.get("Title"));
                System.out.print("Longitude :" + bloodbankMapData.get("Longitude"));
                System.out.print("Latitude :" + bloodbankMapData.get("Latitude"));
                System.out.print("Address :" + bloodbankMapData.get("Address"));
            }
            for (int i=0;i<hospitalList.size();i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hospitalMapData = hospitalList.get(i);
                System.out.print("ID :" + hospitalMapData.get("ID"));
                System.out.print("Title :" + hospitalMapData.get("Title"));
                System.out.print("Longitude :" + hospitalMapData.get("Longitude"));
                System.out.print("Latitude :" + hospitalMapData.get("Latitude"));
                System.out.print("Address :" + hospitalMapData.get("Address"));
            }

        }catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject dataJsonObject = new JSONObject(toParseData);
                JSONArray ambulanceArray = dataJsonObject.getJSONArray("ambulance");
                for(int i=0;i<ambulanceArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject ambulanceChildNode = ambulanceArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String ID=ambulanceChildNode.getString("ID");
                }
                JSONArray bloodBankArray = dataJsonObject.getJSONArray("bloodbank");
                for(int i=0;i<bloodBankArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject ambulanceChildNode = ambulanceArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title=bloodBankArray.getString("Title");
                }
```

.
.
.
.
.

....... and SO ON. DONT BE LAZY. post questions after trying and if you have any problems